# How to align shiny input boxes, specifically selectInput and numericInput

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I'm a shiny newbie and was thrilled when I used SO to figure out how to filter one selectInput based on another.  However, as I added more inputs they became misaligned and I was hoping there was a simple fix.  I do not know HTML at all.  And while I searched for similar questions, the different shiny layouts and other code overhead made it difficult to understand the way to fix.

I'm assuming I just need to include the UI part for a reproducible example rather than confuse future searches with all of the "overhead" of longer code, so I am including the UI here.  Please let me know if I need to include more.

The shiny input is more and more off with additional inputs as you can see:
[image]

Here is the reproducible example:

```
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(headerPanel(strong("Carbohydrate Calculator")),
                
                
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_1',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_2',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_3',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_4',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_5',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_6',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_7',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_8',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    )
                    
                  ),
                  
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_1',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_2',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_3',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_4',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_5',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_6',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_7',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_8',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    )
                    
                    
                  ),
                  
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_1",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                      ),
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_2",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ),
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_3",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ),
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_4",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ),
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_5",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ),
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_6",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ),
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_7",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ),
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_8",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    )
                    
                  ),
                  
                  
                  column(8,
                         tableOutput("my_table"),
                         span(textOutput("my_message"), style="color:red")
                  ) # Column close
                )   # fluidRow close
)                   # fluidPage close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better align the elements in a row, it may be better to fill the elements in a row.  Try this

```
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(headerPanel(strong("Carbohydrate Calculator")),
                
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_11',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_11',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_11",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_12',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_12',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_12",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_13',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_13',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_13",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_14',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_14',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_14",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_15',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_15',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_15",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'cat_16',
                      label   = 'Food Category',
                      choices = c("None", categories)
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'food_16',
                      label   = 'Food Item',
                      choices = foods[1]
                    )),
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "actual_serving_16",
                      label = "How much?",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 100
                    ))
                )
                
                  
                  
                  # column(8,
                  #        tableOutput("my_table"),
                  #        span(textOutput("my_message"), style="color:red")
                  # ) # Column close
                
)                   # fluidPage close

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: YBS, I might put this in a new question, but I noticed when I select a new food category (e.g., a second item), the Food resets to the first food.  Any ideas why?  It seems like it triggers the choices = foods[1].  I realize you might need the rest of the code, but wondering if you might know off the top of your head

Comment: choices should be multiple.  foods[1] is a single element.  Please modify as: `choices = foods`, and `selected=foods[1]`.

Comment: I will have to post another question.  I tried that but it still resets.

Comment: Here is the new posted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648754/shiny-how-to-prevent-selectinput-from-being-reset-by-selecting-a-second-selecti